# ffmpeg works fine most of the time in java except for this command (merging), and this command works fine directly in terminal

Tags: java, ffmpeg

When I run this from the command line it works (merges two videos side by side):

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/ron/Dropbox/JAMR/Technology/workspace/JAMR/sandbox/test.mov -i /Users/ron/Dropbox/JAMR/Technology/workspace/JAMR/sandbox/test1.mov -filter_complex "[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w" /Users/ron/Dropbox/JAMR/Technology/workspace/JAMR/sandbox/merged.mov
```

However, when I run it in java, I get this from the console:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fd44ad00440] No such filter: '"'
Error configuring filters.
```

here is the text I am returning (copied directly) which is what I am sending to be executed.  It is exactly the same, except I use the escape character before the quote symbol, so a " becomes \":

```
"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /Users/ron/Dropbox/JAMR/Technology/workspace/JAMR/sandbox/test.mov -i /Users/ron/Dropbox/JAMR/Technology/workspace/JAMR/sandbox/test1.mov -filter_complex \"[0:v:0]pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [bg][1:v:0]overlay=w\" /Users/ron/Dropbox/JAMR/Technology/workspace/JAMR/sandbox/merged.mov";
```

All other ffmpeg tests have worked except this.... (the only one where I use a " character)

Can anyone figure it out?

Comment: If you print the string to the console, do you get the first command?

Comment: yes, the command is the String printed to the console.  When I copy and paste it into terminal, it works.  However, if I run the process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should split your command in Java into a String array and then pass it to getRuntime().exec(String[])

Short example:

```
String cmd[] = new String[]{
                "ffmpeg",
                "-r", String.valueOf(20/30f), 
                "-i", "assets/IMAG0054_BURST%03d.jpg",
                "-i","assets/logo.png",
                "-i","assets/guitar_tuning.wav","-r", "24", "-codec:a", "mp3",
                "-filter_complex","[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10,"+
                "drawtext=fontfile=assets/OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text=1st scene:x=0:y=0:fontsize=100:fontcolor=white:enable='between(t,0.5,2.5)'," +
                "drawtext=enable='between(t,2.6,5.5)':fontfile=assets/OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text=2nd scene:x=0:y=0:fontsize=100:fontcolor=white," +
                "drawtext=enable='between(t,5.6,8.8)':fontfile=assets/OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text=3rd scene:x=0:y=0:fontsize=100:fontcolor=white," +
                "drawtext=enable='between(t,8.9,30)':fontfile=assets/OpenSans-Regular.ttf:text=4rd scene:x=0:y=0:fontsize=100:fontcolor=white" +
                "[out]",
                "-map", "[out]", "-map", "2:0",
                "-acodec","mp3",
                //"-shortest " +
                "simple_lapse.mp4"};

Process ffmpeg = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I could be wrong, but is the primary difference of your suggestion changing the coding style of how to generate the String command?  Whether I pass a command as a String[] or as a fully formatted String,  at the end of the day, it should be the same String end result.  Or is there something else besides code style in your suggestion I don't understand?

Comment: Yes, there is huge difference between running command as one String and String array... I was facing same problem few dayes ago and found out that passing args as String[] works perfectly fine ( and passing one string is not ). Try to use String[] and don't use QOUTE marks ( look at my example )

Comment: wow!  you are correct, it made a difference!  It's still not working 100% but MAJOR step forward.  For some reason the right side screen is small than the left, but at least a file is generated!  I'm having other issues, so I will move everything to a String array and create a new ticket with issues.  Thanks!